# Easily Update Table From Remote File

Tags: php, sql, html

I apologize if I'm missing any details to this question, I really don't know what I need.

I've got a table of the "Top X" of the week that I need to update daily. I want it to be as easy 'in and out' as possible to update.

Ideally I'd like the information taken from a file I can edit and upload to my server and auto-update the table, or something like this.

My list of Top 10 'xyz' is currently static. This means every time the order changes (which could be 20 times a day) I have to manually update the table. Is there a way I can dynamically update my table in accordance to the "official list" on another website?

Is this possible? I'm going to guess they will require PHP, but really haven't gone into too much of it. Any links to help me accomplish this are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here are a few.

1. Just Edit the HTML
2. Read from a database.
3. Dynamically load txt file (eg JSON,CSS) via JavaScript.
4. Dynamically load html file (with just the table) via JavaScript.

Comment: Hi Hogan,

I don't think I expressed my need correctly. My list of Top 10 'xyz' is currently static. This means every time the order changes (which could be 20 times a day) I have to manually update the table. Is there a way I can dynamically update my table in accordance to the "official list" on another website?

Comment: @BarelyCodes : Does the site provide an API?  If so you are golden.  Otherwise you will need to write a program to scrape the data (in JavaScript or other) then do one of the things I describe above.

Comment: No API is provided. Could you please toss me a link showing the overview of what needs to be done to scrape the data? I assume I could just use a macro to insert the data from the scraped file into the table?